# Connect to sleeping computer without access to router

Tags: windows-7, sleep, teamviewer

is there any way how to connect to sleeping PC remotely without static IP and access to my router?

I know that dynamic IP should not be a problem because TeamViewer can work without static ip.

However they are using WOL for waking up sleeping computer and they provide 2 ways of configuration one needs computer in same lan, second need access to the router configuration.

Is there any way how to do it when any of these two option is not possible?

The PC is SLEEPing not in hibernate mod and with Win 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You can only send WakeOnLan over a local lan.

Waking up a computer from a sleeping state(motherboard is still listening for network traffic), you have to be connected locally to the same network.
You can do this externally by creating a VPN tunnel into the router. After which, you'll be able to wake the computer(assuming you're software sends the WakeOnLan Magic Packet AND the computer bios has been set to allow wake on lan as a feature) The technology for WOL is doable but you have to make the neccessary arrangements and test it first before relying on it for day to day use.